# Disabling auto identation when saving a file

Tags: indentation, c++, doom

I'm using Doom Emacs (pretty much vanilla with a few packages) and whenever I save a file, Emacs automatically changes the indentation.

For example, if I'm editing a C++ file like this:

```
FoamFile
{
    version     2.0;
    format      ascii;
    class       dictionary;
    object      controlDict;
}

application     icoFoam;

startFrom       startTime;

startTime       0;

stopAt          endTime;

endTime         20;

deltaT          0.05;

writeControl    runTime;

writeInterval   1;

purgeWrite      0;

writeFormat     ascii;

writePrecision  8;

writeCompression off;

timeFormat      general;

timePrecision   6;

runTimeModifiable true;
```

When I save it, Emacs changes the indentation like this:

```
FoamFile {
  version 2.0;
  format ascii;
  class dictionary;
  object controlDict;
}

application icoFoam;

startFrom startTime;

startTime 0;

stopAt endTime;

endTime 20;

deltaT 0.05;

writeControl runTime;

writeInterval 1;

purgeWrite 0;

writeFormat ascii;

writePrecision 8;

writeCompression off;

timeFormat general;

timePrecision 6;

runTimeModifiable true;
```

I tried disabling `electric-indent-mode`, but it did not work.

How can I modify this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to disable `(format +onsave)` in my `init.el` file. This is, just commenting out said line in:

```
:editor
       (evil +everywhere); come to the dark side, we have cookies
       file-templates    ; auto-snippets for empty files
       fold              ; (nigh) universal code folding
       ;;(format +onsave)  ; automated prettiness
       ;;god               ; run Emacs commands without modifier keys
       ;;lispy             ; vim for lisp, for people who don't like vim
       ;;multiple-cursors  ; editing in many places at once
       ;;objed             ; text object editing for the innocent
       ;;parinfer          ; turn lisp into python, sort of
       ;;rotate-text       ; cycle region at point between text candidates
       snippets          ; my elves. They type so I don't have to
       ;;word-wrap         ; soft wrapping with language-aware indent
```

made Emacs work as I wanted.